# Dynamically Change as.POSIXlt Value

Tags: r, if-statement, timestamp

In R, I am trying to read a file that has a timestamp, and update the timestamp based on the condition of another field. The below code works with no problem:

```
t <- data.frame(user = as.character(c("bshelton@email1.com", "lwong@email1.com")), 
                last_update = rep(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time(), tz = "America/Los_Angeles"), 2))
Sys.sleep(5)
t$last_update <- as.POSIXlt(ifelse(t$user == "bshelton@email1.com", Sys.time(), t$last_update), origin = "1970-01-01")  
print(t)
```

**The problem is when I read an existing file and try to dynamically change an `as.POSIXlt` value.** The following code is producing the error that accompanies it in the code block afterwards:

```
t <- data.frame(user = as.character(c("bshelton@email1.com", "lwong2@email1.com")), 
                last_update = rep(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time(), tz = "America/Los_Angeles"), 2))

write.csv(t, "so_question.csv", row.names = FALSE)
t <- read.csv("so_question.csv")

t$last_update <- as.POSIXlt(t$last_update)
Sys.sleep(5)
t$last_update <- as.POSIXlt(ifelse(t$user == "bshelton@email1.com", Sys.time(), t$last_update), origin = "1970-01-01")
```

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.default(ifelse(t$user == "bshelton@email1.com", Sys.time(),  : 
  do not know how to convert 'ifelse(t$user == "bshelton@email1.com", Sys.time(), t$last_update)' to class “POSIXlt”
In addition: Warning message:
In ans[!test & ok] <- rep(no, length.out = length(ans))[!test &  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Answer (score 1):

The first case is curiously working only because you don't have what you think—those datetimes are in fact POSIXct, not POSIXlt:

```r
last_update <- rep(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time(), tz = "America/Los_Angeles"), 2)
str(last_update)
#>  POSIXlt[1:2], format: "2019-07-28 20:52:10" "2019-07-28 20:52:10"

t <- data.frame(user = as.character(c("bshelton@email1.com", "lwong@email1.com")), 
                last_update = last_update)
str(t)
#> 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ user       : Factor w/ 2 levels "bshelton@email1.com",..: 1 2
#>  $ last_update: POSIXct, format: "2019-07-28 20:52:10" "2019-07-28 20:52:10"
```

If you dig into `?data.frame`, it says

> `data.frame` converts each of its arguments to a data frame by calling `as.data.frame(optional = TRUE)`. As that is a generic function, methods can be written to change the behaviour of arguments according to their classes: R comes with many such methods. Character variables passed to data.frame are converted to factor columns unless protected by `I` or argument `stringsAsFactors` is false. If a list or data frame or matrix is passed to `data.frame` it is as if each component or column had been passed as a separate argument (except for matrices protected by `I`).

This is what's happening: `as.data.frame.POSIXlt` in fact converts to POSIXct:

```r
now <- Sys.time()
str(now)
#>  POSIXct[1:1], format: "2019-07-28 22:50:12"

str(data.frame(time = now))
#> 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  1 variable:
#>  $ time: POSIXct, format: "2019-07-28 22:50:12"

as.data.frame.POSIXlt
#> function (x, row.names = NULL, optional = FALSE, ...) 
#> {
#>     value <- as.data.frame.POSIXct(as.POSIXct(x), row.names, 
#>         optional, ...)
#>     if (!optional) 
#>         names(value) <- deparse(substitute(x))[[1L]]
#>     value
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x7fc938a11060>
#> <environment: namespace:base>
```

More immediately, since `Sys.time()` returns a POSIXct object, `ifelse(t$user == "bshelton@email1.com", Sys.time(), t$last_update)` in the second case is getting a POSIXct object for one observation and POSIXlt for the other. The POSIXlt object's `class` attribute is dropped by `ifelse` revealing the list underneath, which `ifelse` then doesn't know how to turn into a vector together with the unclassed POSIXct object (which is just a number).

The solution here, then, is to follow the hint `data.frame` is giving you and use POSIXct instead of POSIXlt.

If you *really* want to make it work with POSIXlt, you can iterate over the conditions and POSIXlt vector with `Map` with `if`/`else` (which maintain attributes including class, but only handle scalar conditions) and coerce the resulting list back to a vector with `do.call(c, ...)`:

```r
t <- data.frame(user = as.character(c("bshelton@email1.com", "lwong@email1.com")), 
                last_update = rep(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time(), tz = "America/Los_Angeles"), 2))
t$last_update <- as.POSIXlt(t$last_update)

t$last_update <- do.call(c, Map(
    function(condition, last_update){
        if (condition) {
            as.POSIXlt(Sys.time() + 5)
        } else {
            last_update
        }
    },
    condition = t$user == "bshelton@email1.com",
    last_update = t$last_update
))
t
#>                  user         last_update
#> 1 bshelton@email1.com 2019-07-28 23:11:04
#> 2    lwong@email1.com 2019-07-28 23:10:59
```

...but frankly that's a little silly. Just use POSIXct instead, and your life will be better.

Comment: Will accept tomorrow morning once I have a chance to run and validate. Thanks!